# Send compressed log file to ftp

Tags: java, ftp, log4j

Is it possible send file using log4j to ftp with compression?, I have read this [log4j appenders](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#SyslogAppender) but I don't understand.

Hi again, I have this appenders but does not work

```
<appenders name="FileDebugFTP" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="file" value="test.log" />
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="8000KB"/>
    <Syslog format="RFC5424" host="localhost" port="21"
        protocol="TCP" includeMDC="true"
        facility="FTP" enterpriseNumber="18060" newLine="true"/>
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
        <param name="levelMin" value="DEBUG" />
        <param name="levelMax" value="FATAL" />
    </filter>
    </layout>
</appenders>
```

Somebody could help me? Sorry but I am new with log4j and I need pass user and pass.

Answer (score 0):

Hio Jijreina,

Been having a look around as this isn't my specialty  but this looks like  good start.

> http://www.simonsite.org.uk Two appenders are provided for use with Log4J 1.2.x. Each is packaged as a separate component in its own JAR, with its own test report, and test coverage report.

**Comparison Matrix **

> Compare the features of the TimeAndSizeRollingAppender, out-of-the-box Log4J Appenders, and the Log4J Extras RollingFileAppender.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple option could be available .. but here's the work around. Create custom email appender that compresses and sends the file to the FTP server instead of actually sending the mail.

Basically, you just need some custom appender that can do what you want.